# Unintentionally redirect to startpage in javascript

Tags: javascript, redirect

To get to the point:

This is my HTML file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Ex-Escape</title>
<!-- all game scripts have to be included here -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="src/game.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/playerSettings.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/jsonLib.js"></script>
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', Game.start);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

It loads my my Object Game with the function start.

```
start: function start() {
document.write("<p onclick='Game.new()' style='display: inline-block; border: 2px solid white; border-radius: 5px;'><b>New Game</b></p> <p onclick='Game.load()' style='display: inline-block; border: 2px solid white; border-radius: 5px;'><b>Load Game</b></p>");
}
```

At this point all works fine! If i click New Game i get to my form where I can create my character (its a game).

```
document.write("</br></br><input type='submit' onclick='Game.storePlayerData(); Game.intro();' value='Get Citypass'>");
```

Now it should "redirect" me to the next page. Game.intro()

```
intro: function intro() {
    document.write("<p>Welcome</p>");

    //set Style
    document.write("<link href='css/gamelayout.css' rel='stylesheet'>");
    document.close();
},
```

But all I got is a "Welcome" for a very short time, and after this very short time I'm back at the start page. I don't know why.
It seems that I can go from start to new character, but after this every other "redirect" will go to the start Page.

Its not the window.addEventListener('load', Game.start); at the begining. I guess. Game.start() instead of eventlistener will cause the same result.

Comment: What did you expect clicking on a submit button to do?

Comment: Type="submit" ... This causes a real redirect. Dont use submit if you dont want this to happen...

Comment: @Quentin the submit button will start Game.storePlayerData() and Game.intro(). First function will store the information about the player and intro() is the next site.

Comment: @Jonasw I tried <button> instead of <input type='submit'>, Same problem.

Comment: @MarcJansen — And what will the submit button do after the JavaScript has finished? It *is* a **submit** button (and so is a `<button>` element without a `type` attribute).

Comment: @Quentin I feel so bad in my whole existence now. I replaced the button with a <p onclick...> and it worked. Omg I will keep that in mind. Thanks.

Comment: @MarcJansen — Paragraphs are not interactive elements. They won't be treated like them by screen readers. They won't appear in the focus order. Use a type="button" input.

Comment: @MarcJansen -- this sounds silly, but <button> has a default type of  "submit", so you must set it to "button", or else it will act as a submit. That is, <button type="button"> (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

Comment: Thanks @JohnHenry